# "Query compilation failed" for redshift query

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm using psql (postgresql 10.1) to access a table on AWS/redshift.

The following query gives me a very cryptic error:

```
=> select to_timestamp(json_extract_path_text(data, 'scheduling_at'), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS"Z"') as ts from my_table;
ERROR:  Error:
DETAIL:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Error:
  code:      14001
  context:   'code != 0' - Query compilation failed for /rds/bin/padb.1.0.1582/data/exec/182/2
  query:     1095356
  location:  cg_util.cpp:853
  process:   padbmaster [pid=1753]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Each part of the query works individually (that is, my usage of `json_extract_path_text` and `to_timestamp` seem to work in isolation). And furthermore I suspect the issue is in redshift because using the full query on a hardcoded `data` value works:

```
=> select to_timestamp(json_extract_path_text('{"scheduling_at":"2017-12-20T21:35:25.405Z"}', 'scheduling_at'), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS"Z"') as ts;
             ts
----------------------------
 2017-12-20 21:35:25.405+00
(1 row)
```

Any ideas? This is a pretty frustrating issue and I haven't found anything about "error code 14001" googling around.

EDIT: minimal sample table which gives the error:

```
=> select * from my_table;
                  id                  |                     data
--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------
 bca48053-3170-4c00-a2da-a9fc6ad6f888 | {"scheduling_at":"2017-12-20T21:35:25.405Z"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: You probably need to cast the data::text and coalesce nulls.

Comment: @jackotonye, I think not, as `json_extract_path_text` works fine over the table and returns all non-null (and valid) values, not to mention I would expect a more helpful error message if either of those were the case. But just for completeness I tried with your suggestions and get the same error.

Comment: Can u add the sample table data.

Comment: done @jackotonye

Comment: to_char(data at time zone 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS"Z"')